# Reset everything in the game

Tags: diablo-iii

I've played Diablo 3 a bit when it was released. Is it possible to reset my achievements, quest progress, artisans and everything to have a fresh start with Reaper of Souls?

Comment: If you only played on a single region, you could start in a new region, that's a new clean slate.

Comment: Except without achievements, but that's a good idea. Now I have to check the lag of other region servers so I won't get killed at level 59 in hardcore :)

Comment: Including achievements. Even including friend list. *everything* is separate in different regions. For your lag concern: I've never had problems playing on the US servers from the EU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a region where you haven't played before you can change your region and start with a completely blank slate.

*Everything* is region specific. Achievements, gold, friend list, characters, artisans, ...

The only nuisance is that the launcher does *not* properly switch region (the dropdown stays changed, but it still shows your online friends from your "main" region).

I've never had any lag concerns while playing on the US servers based in Europe. I can't remember how good/bad the Asia servers were since I only played on these when the EU/US servers were both overloaded during the initial launch.

Answer (score 3):

You won't find this information on any Blizzard forums or help center (because it is not something players normally want to do).

However I would recommend to open a help request ticket. explaining your case. You are much likely to have a answer from them. Either it is positive or negative, in which case you will have a reason why it is not possible.

The only option I see would be to buy the game again under an other Battle.net account or the same but on a different region.

Comment: Diablo III is a global region game.  Which means you can only have a single Diablo III license attached to a Battle.net account.